# Get WP_Query Object with mysql custom query in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a custom mysql query

> $search_query_location="SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_postmeta wher post_id IN
>   (112233,445566,77441,145,254)";

I can run above query to get data with "wpdb" function like

```
$wpdb->get_results($search_query_location, OBJECT);
```

It return array of post like

Array

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 11923
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2015-06-23 08:05:30
         )
)
```

but I need

> WP_Query Object in return of "new WP_Query" function

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        ()
     [posts] =Array ()
)
```

If I use WP_Query along with the arguments `post__in` and `posts_per_page` then result come in **WP_Query Object** with default sorting order (that is post id) but I need sorting order that I have defined in my custom query that is (112233,445566,77441,145,254) posts ids 
How can I get **WP_Query Object** using custom mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `orderby` parameter accepts the `post__in` sorting value as a possible way to sort posts returned. With `orderby` set to `post__in`, the posts will be returned in the order they are entered into the `post__in` parameter.

The following code

```
$args = [
    'post__in' =>[3, 1, 2],
    'orderby' => 'post__in'
];

$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

will return posts 1,2, and 3 in the following order

> 3, 1, 2